# Generating urls for a sparql query which is using dbpedia

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sparql, dbpedia

I'm working on developing a front end for a service where, currently, users come up with their own SPARQL query and set their parameters within that, for example:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX framenet: <http://www.newsreader-project.eu/framenet/>
PREFIX gaf: <http://groundedannotationframework.org/files/2014/01/>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX sem: <http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/2009/11/sem/>
# All allowed parameters:
# output: html, offset: 0, limit: 100, 
# uri.0: {uri_0}, uri.1: {uri_1}
# filter_block: ?filterfield bif:contains "{string}" ., date_filter_block: ?d owltime:year "{datefilter}"^^xsd:int . 
# uri_filter_block:  ?filterfield rdfs:label ?_label . ?_label bif:contains "{string}" .

SELECT ?event (COUNT(*) AS ?event_size) ?datetime ?event_label
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?event ?datetime ?event_label
    WHERE {
      { ?event sem:hasActor {uri_0} } UNION { ?event sem:hasPlace {uri_0} }
      ?event sem:hasTime ?t ; rdfs:label ?event_label .
      ?t owltime:inDateTime ?d .
      ?d owltime:year "{datefilter}"^^xsd:int . 
      ?t rdfs:label ?datetimetmp .
      FILTER (regex(?datetimetmp,"\\d{4}-\\d{2}"))
      BIND (SUBSTR(?datetimetmp,1,10) AS ?datetime)
    }
    ORDER BY ?datetime
    OFFSET 0
    LIMIT 100
  }
  ?event ?p ?o .
}
GROUP BY ?event ?datetime ?event_label
ORDER BY ?datetime
```

and a page like [this](https://newsreader.scraperwiki.com/summary_of_events_with_actor?uris.0=dbpedia:Thierry_Henry) is generated which displays the results of the query as a table.

What I'm trying to do is create a page which the user can use to enter their desired parameters in an 'easier' way. So, instead of typing `limit:100` in the SPARQL query, I've provided them with a text box entitled 'Limit' which they then enter a value into. I also have a drop down list which lists all of the different query types (such as 'Get events mentioning a named actor' which I have shown you here, or others such as 'Get the properties of a type' or 'Get events with a specific frame net value').

I have an index.html file and a code.js file and, up until now, I've simply had a page with text boxes and a submit button which, when clicked upon/enter is pressed, a function is ran which uses an ajax request to 'pull' the table from a url that I've generated, such as the page of results I linked to up above. This url is generated in the following way:

```
var runQuery = function move(actor, pageNum) {
    var initUrl = "https://newsreader.scraperwiki.com/{0}/page/{1}?uris.0={2}"
    var queryUrl = initUrl.replace("{1}", pageNum);
    var queryUrl = queryUrl.replace("{2}", "dbpedia:" + actor);
    limit = $(textInput[1]).val();
    offset = $(textInput[2]).val();
    stringFilter = $(textInput[3]).val();
    dateFilter = $(textInput[4]).val();
    framenet = $(textInput[5]).val();
    if (limit != "") {queryUrl += ("&limit=" + limit)};
    if (offset != "") {queryUrl += ("&offset=" + offset)};
    if (stringFilter != "") {queryUrl += ("&filter=" + stringFilter)};
    if (dateFilter != "") {queryUrl += ("&datefilter=" + dateFilter)};
    //...more code follows...
```

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/SophieBuckley/newsreaderstuff/blob/master/code.js).

This all works fine for what I've done so far, but I'm having trouble trying to think of ways to concisely alter the `var queryUrl = queryUrl.replace("{2}", "dbpedia:" + actor;` line in particular and the rest of the code to account for the different prefixes used for different query types (in the SPARQL query up above it is `PREFIX dbpedia: <http...`, but it is sometimes `PREFIX dbo: <http...`, etc).

After that long winded explanation, what I want to know is if there is an alternative to manually manipulating `queryUrl` and using a load of conditional statements to account for all of the different query types and, if so, how can I do it? I'm very new to any kind of web stuff and I'm a bit lost! Any advice on how to approach accounting for the different query types as concisely as possible would be great. The only way I can think of how to do it at the minute is to have some sort of code that says...

```
if (actor != "") {
    queryUrl = queryUrl.replace("{2}", "dbpedia:" + actor);
} else if (....) {
    queryUrl = queryUrl.replace("{2}", "dbo:" + ....);
} else... etc
```

.. (where actor is referring to the name of a thing) but I think doing it this way would be clunky and would get confusing with all of the different formats that would need to be accounted for.

Thanks in advance, and if any more information is needed about my problem then please don't hesitate to tell me!

*edit*: I've since came to the conclusion that dbpedia-spotlight isn't very useful for my problem that I've highlighted in this question.

Comment: Without this being a proper answer, I'd suggest that rather than using prefixed names in the query string (e.g., "dbpedia:So_and_So" or "dbo:So_and_so"), if you always use absolute URIs, then you don't have to worry about any particular what to concatenate `actor` with.  Then you're just left with the question of "given a value of `actor`, what URI should I use?  That might be an easier question to answer, and then you just replace "{2}" with "<"+uriForActor(actor)+">".

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Any kind of advice is great, thanks! Your idea makes a lot of sense, I guess I've tried to approach it in a similar way, but absolute URIs are a new concept to me. Sorry to be a pain, but do you know of any resources that would help me in making use of absolute URIs in this instance? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, "absolute URI" wasn't the right term to use, since things like `dbpedia:foo` *do* represent absolute URIs.  What I meant was that `dbpedia:` is a prefix for `http://dbpedia.org/resource/`, so `dbpedia:foo` is actually `http://dbpedia.org/resource/foo`.  `dbo:` is (probably) `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`, so `dbo:Film` is actually `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film`.  The big if/else/else if block that you have seems to be building a prefixed name—if you could just generate the full URI from `actor`, then you could just replace `{2}` with that.  I.e., something like…

Comment: … `queryUrl = queryUrl.replace("{2}", "<"+getUriForActor(actor)+">");`, with no need for any if/else/else-if messiness.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Oh I see, yeah, I got a bit confused when I was googling the term! But I understand what you mean now, thank you very much! I'll give your suggestion a go and see what I can do. :)

Comment: I'd also point out that SPARQL actually has a more general method of doing things like "parameter" replacement:  VALUES blocks.  You can write, e.g., `select ?x ?y where { ?x ?p ?y . filter( ?y < ?z ) }`, you can append, e.g., `values (?p ?z) { (ex:age 40) }` to the query to fix the values of `?p` and `?z`. That might help in avoiding injection attacks (e.g., think about what would happen if someone managed to get the value for uri_0 to be `ex:someActor } UNION { ?s ?p ?o`;  you'd end up adding an additional UNION block that might do something malicious, or leak information.

Comment: But all in all, it sounds like you've got text coming in, and that text is supposed to the be name of an actor, or something like that.  Wouldn't it make more sense to actually search for resources that have that as a label?  E.g., instead of trying to generate `dbpedia:Richard_Dreyfuss` from the string `"Richard Dreyfuss"`, why not just query with `?actor rdfs:label ?label . filter ( str(?label) = ?actorName )` where `?actorName` is provided by the user?

Comment: Mostly because I'm approaching this project with no experience with SPARQL/query languages and the queries have already been prewritten by other colleagues of mine. I haven't felt competent enough to deal with doing any sort of searching myself and I was just instructed to work around the existing queries that have already been written and present the front end part for the user to interact with, if that makes sense. But your suggestion is a good one and a valid one and it's definitely worth raising it to my colleagues. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to access [the API page output as JSON](https://newsreader.scraperwiki.com/?output=json) so that I can access the queries from there instead of accounting for every type of queryUrl. Any additional thoughts and answers would be greatly appreciated, but are now unnecessary.

Thanks!